# Understanding DNN on existing website

Tags: dotnetnuke

I started working on an existing website that uses DNN.  I am having difficulty understanding and accessing DNN in their staging/test environment.  In IIS there are a few different websites.  How can I figure out how to get to the main Admin DNN screen by looking at the information in IIS and exploring to files.  Once there I need to apply new licenses for DNN.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: By just looking at IIS alone, I don't think you're going to be able to do that. The username and password will be stored in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I was trying to figure out how to figure out the URL to access DNN.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In IIS, right click on the website and choose the Manage Bindings option, that will show you the various Host Names (URLS) that are configured.

Try those URLs, and then put ?CTL=login on the end of the URL to get DNN to load the login control. From there you can login with a HOST or ADMIN account, HOST/SuperUser account would be best, as you can then go to the Host/Portals (Site Management?) page and see how many different "sites" are configured within the DNN installation.